# Add data into firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am entering a user into firebase like:

```
private void Database(String mail, String password){
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mail, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d("CreateUser", "createUserWithEmail:success");
                        showToast("User successfully created");
                        insertUserData();
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w("CreateUser", "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        showToast("Authentication failed. User exist!");
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Now I want to add additional user information that will be linked on the user above calling ***insertUserData()***

I created the "User" class that looks like:

```
    public class User {

        private String name;
        private String surname;
        private String phone;
        private String address;
        private String country;
        private String zip;

        public User(){
        }

        public User (String mail, String surname, String phone, String address, String country, String zip){
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
            this.phone = phone;
            this.address = address;
            this.country = country;
            this.zip = zip;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
//...
//...
```

My question is how should I insert additional user data into firebase that links on Users, I tried to create a new database in firebase that looks like: [image: screenshot]

And in Android studio:

```
private void insertUserData(){
        FirebaseUser username = auth.getCurrentUser();
        String userId = username.getUid();
        Firebase rootRef = new Firebase(MYURL);
        Firebase userRef = rootRef.child("Users");
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Test");
        user.setSurname("Test");
        userRef.child(userId).setValue(user);
    }
```

But I am not sure what ***MYURL*** stands for, I heard that it is for the old firebase and that I should swap it with something new.

Update:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will set the user according to it's uid provided by `FirebaseAuth`

```
private void insertUserData(){
    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    String uid = user.getUid();
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
    user.put("first", "Ada");
    user.put("last", "Lovelace");
    user.put("born", 1815);

    // Add a new document with a generated ID
    db.collection("users")
            .document(uid)
            .set(user);
}
```

Use only Firestore :

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1'
}
```

Comment: Thank You, now I am getting this error: https://ibb.co/n6dDJfm, I guess something is wrong with my implements so I'll provide them in original post.

Comment: Which type of database your trying to implement in your application realtime or firestore ?

Comment: I would love to use firestore in my application

Comment: Then remove the realtime database from your dependencies so it can work properly as you expected

Comment: Tried to remove firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1, firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6, firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0, firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0 and it asks me with "ALT + enter" to implement dependecy, after implementation error is still the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: Don't remove only use those 3 dependencies i have provided so it will work as you expected

Comment: I did and I synced it succesfully but error is still there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204490/discussion-between-ashish-and-thename).

Answer (score 1):

The code that you are using is for realtime database, but the picture in the question is for firestore. If you want to use firestore then you have to do the following:

```
Map<String, Object> userData = new HashMap<>();
userData.put("name", "john");
userData.put("address", "address");
userData.put("country", "USA");

db.collection("User").document("User")
        .set(userData)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
            }
        });
```

Check here for more info:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: Thank You, what is "db" in this case and how can I init it. Is it better to use firestore and link it on Users over UserID?

Comment: db is this `FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();` yes u can link using firebase auth and firestore

Comment: @PeterHaddad better provide proper code for firestore

Comment: It works now, but it is always writing at same fields. I guess that somehow I have to create new user at collection in firebase from android studio and add data for that user?

Comment: @TheName Check the code it will work if you want explanation me or peter will explain you

Answer (score 1):

If you have copied google-services.json file into your project then you dont have to worry about **MYURL** i have modified your **insertUserData** function, which stores users data into firestore database

```
    private void insertUserData(){
        FirebaseUser username = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String userId = username.getUid();
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Test");
        user.setSurname("Test");
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("users")
                .document(userId)
                .set(user, SetOptions.merge());
    }
```

Use option **SetOptions.merge()** if you dont want your existing data to be wiped out

Comment: I can't see any data in firebase and in logcat there is error: java.io.IOException: Invalid device key response.

Comment: it seems you  have not set your SHA1 in the project, try adding debug sha1 to project by following steps, generate debug sha1 -> open firebase project -> click on settings icon(next to project overview) -> click on the package name of the project at bottom -> add fingerprint -> copy the sha1